# assign php session variables on button submit w/o name

Tags: php, session-variables

What I need to do is store session variables on a button event listener in php. The code I have below is for the button and is unchangeable so I have to work with it. I need to get the "email" and "username" from the form and store them as session variables in php.

```
<div class="pmpro_submit">

                <span id="pmpro_submit_span">
                   <input type="hidden" name="submit-checkout" value="1" />
                   <input type="submit" class="pmpro_btn pmpro_btn-submit-checkout" value="Submit and Confirm &raquo;" />
                </span>


<span id="pmpro_processing_message" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

the input type="submit" is the button but there's no way (so far) to get this html code to ever work with the php below. I put the name2 variable just to test if it's getting there but it won't. This is truly a stumper

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])===true)  
{ 
$_SESSION['name2'] ="fred";
$_SESSION['uersname'] = $_POST['username'];
}
```

Comment: FYI you don't have an input button thats named as `submit`

Comment: I know I don't that's the entire crux of the problem

Comment: then just add it, very easy to type

Comment: the html is provided by backend code that I cannot change.

Comment: then just check if the form is submitted, there are plenty of ways to check whether if its submitted, if you can't rely with the markup name, just use another way, there are already a lot of posts regarding that, just search `php check if post submit`

Comment: not that simple. I tried several of the solutions and none of them work